# Python3 getting list item index returning empty error

Tags: list, python-3.x, indexing

code:

```
            other_users=User.objects.filter(logged_in=False)

            for other_user in other_users:
                other_posts=Post.objects.filter(author=other_user)
                print('[!] Collecting other_posts from other_user => {} [{}] [!]'.format(other_user,other_posts))
                try:
                    for other_post in other_posts:
                        print('[=] other_post: {}'.format(other_post))
                        if other_post.likes==0:
                            print('[=] other_post with 0 likes: {}'.format(other_post))
                            for like in range(max_likes_per_user):
                                rand_post=random.choice(other_posts)
                                print('[+] Random post => {} : TYPE[{}]'.format(rand_post,type(rand_post)))
                                post_index=other_posts.index(rand_post)
                                print('[!] Post index: {}'.format(post_index))
                                other_posts.pop(post_index)
                                print('[+] Liking {} POST'.format(rand_post))
                                rand_post.likes+=1
                                rand_post.save()
                                print('[!] Saving like [!]')
                except Exception as e:
                    print('[-] Error: [-]\n\n'.format(e))
                    done=True
```

I'm trying to figure out where the problem is for the last 1h and still can't find it.

I'm trying to get the index of a random choice from a list, but whenever I get to that part, program exits with empty error.

The part:

```
post_index=other_posts.index(rand_post)
print('[!] Post index: {}'.format(post_index))
```

and anything after that is not returning anything, and skipping directly towards Exception, however, e variable is always empty and I'm not getting the error output.

I'd like to know why is the post_index variable not getting any data and why is it skipping to Exception part. What seem to be bad in the code?

These are the outputs I get:

```
[!] Collecting other_posts from other_user => Robot Tyler 1 [<QuerySet [<Post: Robot Tyler 1 - Title 1>, <Post: Robot Tyler 1 - Title 2>, <Post: Robot Tyler 1 - Title 3>, <Post: Robot Tyler 1 - Title 4>]>] [!]
[=] other_post: Robot Tyler 1 - Title 1
[=] other_post with 0 likes: Robot Tyler 1 - Title 1
[+] Random post => Robot Tyler 1 - Title 4 : TYPE[<class 'person.models.Post'>]
[-] Error: [-]


[!] Collecting other_posts from other_user => Robot Tyler 2 [<QuerySet [<Post: Robot Tyler 2 - Title 1>, <Post: Robot Tyler 2 - Title 2>, <Post: Robot Tyler 2 - Title 3>]>] [!]
[=] other_post: Robot Tyler 2 - Title 1
[=] other_post with 0 likes: Robot Tyler 2 - Title 1
[+] Random post => Robot Tyler 2 - Title 1 : TYPE[<class 'person.models.Post'>]
[-] Error: [-]
```

Anyone could tell me where the mistake is?

Comment: this is not the true way of asking question ... ask it clear

Comment: which part of the code has problems ?

Comment: Edited. I'm sorry.

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace of the error. That would be clearer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I added the printouts of the code.

Comment: Would help if you added '{}' in your exception print statement, or flat-out say -    print(e)   - so the exception is actually printed.
My guess is that your data does not support this reference to the index

Comment: you could remove the exception handler that hides the error: that would show the traceback!!

Comment: Okay, eventually I fixed it with @Uvar 's reference. I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `other_posts` variable was `QuerySet` and not a list. So what I did was converting it into a `list(other_posts)`. If anyone seem to understand the reason behind `other_posts` being addressed as `QuerySet`, please explain in comments.

So this is how the code looks like now:

```
other_users=User.objects.filter(logged_in=False)

for other_user in other_users:
    other_posts=Post.objects.filter(author=other_user)
    print('[!] Collecting other_posts from other_user => {} [{}] [!]'.format(other_user,other_posts))
    try:
        for other_post in other_posts:
            print('[=] other_post: {}'.format(other_post))
            if other_post.likes==0:
                print('[=] other_post with 0 likes: {}'.format(other_post))
                for like in range(max_likes_per_user):
                    rand_post=random.choice(other_posts)
                    print('[+] Random post => {} : TYPE[{}]'.format(rand_post,type(rand_post)))
                    post_index=list(other_posts).index(rand_post)
                    print('[!] Post index: {}'.format(post_index))
                    list(other_posts).pop(post_index)
                    print('[+] Liking {} POST'.format(rand_post))
                    rand_post.likes+=1
                    rand_post.save()
                    print('[!] Saving like [!]')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        done=True
```